# VBA Как в цикле сбросить значение переменной когда цикл переходит к обработке следующего значения

Tags: excel, vba

Мне нужно чтобы переменная doctype сбрасывалась до 0 когда цикл переходит к обработке следующего значения,поиск значений ведется в диапазоне ART, задача в том что если данные параллельно от исходного значения будут "Продажа" "Продажа" мы суммируем значения из столбца с отклонением 8, но эта переменная будет работать только для одного item в массиве и сбрасываться при переходе на другой.

```
For Each i In massive
With art
    Set vlue1 = .Find(i)
    str2 = por.Address
    Do
    MsgBox value1.Address
    Set vlue1 = .FindNext(vlue1)
    If por.Offset(1, 4).Value = "Продажа" And por.Offset(1, 5).Value = "Продажа" Then
     doctype = doctype + por.Offset(1, 8)
      Else
       End If
    Loop While Not por Is Nothing And str2 <> por.Address
   End With
 Next i
```

Вот что у меня есть но переменная doctype накапливается и не сбрасывается
Так-же думаю что значение продажа-продажа нужно так-же проверять и в первой найденной ячейке.

Comment: *Мне нужно чтобы переменная doctype сбрасывалась до 0 когда цикл переходит к обработке следующего значения* Ну так и добавь `doctype = 0` в начало цикла `With art`, между ним и `Do`... с другой стороны, так в начале обработки следующего элемента ты пролюбишь в никуда результат для предыдущего.

Comment: Спасибо, поставил спереди doctype = 0 и туже конструкцию IF. Спасибо